# How do I run XEN on arm64 and Qemu 6.0.0 with Linux 4.20.11 as Dom0

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu, u-boot, xen

thank you for reading and appreciated for reply!

I followed this [doc](https://medium.com/@denisobrezkov/xen-on-arm-and-qemu-1654f24dea75) and successfully ran xen 4.12.0 on qemu 3.1.0 with Linux 4.20.11 as Dom0.

Then I tried to use higher version of qemu(qemu 5.1.0 && 6.0.0) to do the same thing, but the process got stuck in the step of running xen with linux.

Here is how I download and build the Qemu 6.0.0:

```sh
wget -nd https://download.qemu.org/qemu-6.0.0.tar.xz
tar xvf qemu-6.0.0.tar.xz
cd qemu-6.0.0
mkdir build
cd build
../configure  --target-list=aarch64-softmmu
make -j8 
./aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64 --version
# QEMU emulator version 6.0.0
# Copyright (c) 2003-2021 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

Then I used this newly built qemu to run with XEN, but got Linux kernel panic error on booting. Here is the log output:

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux Cooper-VirtualBox 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU_Linux

$ ls
Image  Image.gz  rootfs.cpio.gz  u-boot.bin  virt-gicv3.dtb  xen

$ qemu-system-aarch64-600 \
-machine virt,gic-version=3 -machine virtualization=true \
-cpu cortex-a57 -machine type=virt -m 4096 -smp 4 -bios u-boot.bin \
-device loader,file=xen,force-raw=on,addr=0x49000000 \
-device loader,file=Image.gz,addr=0x47000000 \
-device loader,file=virt-gicv3.dtb,addr=0x44000000 \
-nographic -no-reboot -chardev socket,id=qemu-monitor,host=localhost,port=7777,server,nowait,telnet -mon qemu-monitor,mode=readline


U-Boot 2019.01 (Jul 14 2021 - 11:02:43 +0800)

DRAM:  4 GiB
Flash: 128 MiB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    pl011@9000000
Out:   pl011@9000000
Err:   pl011@9000000
Net:   No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
scanning bus for devices...

Device 0: unknown device

Device 0: unknown device
starting USB...
No controllers found
No ethernet found.
No ethernet found.
=> fdt addr 0x44000000
=> fdt set /chosen \#address-cells <1>
=> fdt set /chosen \#size-cells <1>
=> fdt mknod /chosen module@0
=> fdt set /chosen/module@0 compatible "xen,linux-zimage" "xen,multiboot-module"
=> fdt set /chosen/module@0 reg <0x47000000 
Unexpected character '
'
=> fdt set /chosen/module@0 reg <0x47000000 0x7ccfb8>
=> fdt set /chosen/module@0 bootargs "earlyprintk=serial,ttyAMA0
> console=ttyAMA0,115200n8 earlycon=xenboot"
=> fdt resize
=> booti 0x49000000 - 0x44000000
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 44000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x44000000
   reserving fdt memory region: addr=44000000 size=2000
   Loading Device Tree to 00000000ffffa000, end 00000000ffffefff ... OK

Starting kernel ...

 Xen 4.12.0
(XEN) Xen version 4.12.0 (Cooper@) (aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0) debug=n  Wed Jul 14 11:05:52 CST 2021
(XEN) Latest ChangeSet: 
(XEN) Processor: 411fd070: "ARM Limited", variant: 0x1, part 0xd07, rev 0x0
(XEN) 64-bit Execution:
(XEN)   Processor Features: 0000000001000222 0000000000000000
(XEN)     Exception Levels: EL3:No EL2:64+32 EL1:64+32 EL0:64+32
(XEN)     Extensions: FloatingPoint AdvancedSIMD GICv3-SysReg
(XEN)   Debug Features: 0000000010305106 0000000000000000
(XEN)   Auxiliary Features: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
(XEN)   Memory Model Features: 0000000000001124 0000000000000000
(XEN)   ISA Features:  0000000000011120 0000000000000000
(XEN) 32-bit Execution:
(XEN)   Processor Features: 00000131:10011001
(XEN)     Instruction Sets: AArch32 A32 Thumb Thumb-2 Jazelle
(XEN)     Extensions: GenericTimer
(XEN)   Debug Features: 03010066
(XEN)   Auxiliary Features: 00000000
(XEN)   Memory Model Features: 10101105 40000000 01260000 02102211
(XEN)  ISA Features: 02101110 13112111 21232042 01112131 00011142 00011121
(XEN) Generic Timer IRQ: phys=30 hyp=26 virt=27 Freq: 62500 KHz
(XEN) GICv3 initialization:
(XEN)       gic_dist_addr=0x00000008000000
(XEN)       gic_maintenance_irq=25
(XEN)       gic_rdist_stride=0
(XEN)       gic_rdist_regions=1
(XEN)       redistributor regions:
(XEN)         - region 0: 0x000000080a0000 - 0x00000009000000
(XEN) GICv3: 256 lines, (IID 0000043b).
(XEN) GICv3: CPU0: Found redistributor in region 0 @000000004001c000
(XEN) Using scheduler: SMP Credit Scheduler rev2 (credit2)
(XEN) Initializing Credit2 scheduler
(XEN) Allocated console ring of 16 KiB.
(XEN) Bringing up CPU1
(XEN) GICv3: CPU1: Found redistributor in region 0 @000000004003c000
(XEN) Bringing up CPU2
(XEN) GICv3: CPU2: Found redistributor in region 0 @000000004005c000
(XEN) Bringing up CPU3
(XEN) GICv3: CPU3: Found redistributor in region 0 @000000004007c000
(XEN) Adding cpu 3 to runqueue 0
(XEN) CPU 3 booted.
(XEN) Brought up 4 CPUs
(XEN) P2M: 44-bit IPA with 44-bit PA and 8-bit VMID
(XEN) P2M: 4 levels with order-0 root, VTCR 0x80043594
(XEN) I/O virtualisation disabled
(XEN) *** LOADING DOMAIN 0 ***
(XEN) Loading Domd0 kernel from boot module @ 0000000047000000
(XEN) Allocating 1:1 mappings totalling 512MB for dom0:
(XEN) BANK[0] 0x00000060000000-0x00000080000000 (512MB)
(XEN) Grant table range: 0x00000049000000-0x00000049040000
(XEN) Allocating PPI 16 for event channel interrupt
(XEN) Loading zImage from 0000000138000000 to 0000000060080000-00000000612c1200
(XEN) Loading dom0 DTB to 0x0000000068000000-0x0000000068001d0c
(XEN) Initial low memory virq threshold set at 0x4000 pages.
(XEN) Scrubbing Free RAM in background
(XEN) Std. Loglevel: Errors and warnings
(XEN) Guest Loglevel: Nothing (Rate-limited: Errors and warnings)
(XEN) ***************************************************
(XEN) No support for ARM_SMCCC_ARCH_WORKAROUND_1.
(XEN) Please update your firmware.
(XEN) ***************************************************
(XEN) No support for ARM_SMCCC_ARCH_WORKAROUND_1.
(XEN) Please update your firmware.
(XEN) ***************************************************
(XEN) No support for ARM_SMCCC_ARCH_WORKAROUND_1.
(XEN) Please update your firmware.
(XEN) ***************************************************
(XEN) PLEASE SPECIFY dom0_mem PARAMETER - USING 512M FOR NOW
(XEN) ***************************************************
(XEN) 3... 2... 1... 
(XEN) *** Serial input to DOM0 (type 'CTRL-a' three times to switch input)
(XEN) Freed 312kB init memory.
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x411fd070]
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.20.11 (Cooper@Cooper-VirtualBox) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 14 10:53:34 CST 2021
[    0.000000] Machine model: linux,dummy-virt
[    0.000000] earlycon: xenboot0 at I/O port 0x0 (options '')
[    0.000000] printk: bootconsole [xenboot0] enabled
[    0.000000] Xen 4.12 support found
[    0.000000] efi: Getting EFI parameters from FDT:
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 32 MiB at 0x000000007e000000
[    0.000000] NUMA: No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] NUMA: Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000060000000-0x000000007fffffff]
[    0.000000] NUMA: NODE_DATA [mem 0x7dfea840-0x7dfebfff]
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000060000000-0x000000007fffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000060000000-0x000000007fffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000060000000-0x000000007fffffff]
[    0.000000] psci: probing for conduit method from DT.
[    0.000000] psci: PSCIv1.1 detected in firmware.
[    0.000000] psci: Using standard PSCI v0.2 function IDs
[    0.000000] psci: Trusted OS migration not required
[    0.000000] psci: SMC Calling Convention v1.1
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x94/0x40c with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 23 pages/cpu @(____ptrval____) s55704 r8192 d30312 u94208
[    0.000000] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000] CPU features: enabling workaround for ARM erratum 832075
[    0.000000] CPU features: enabling workaround for ARM erratum 834220
[    0.000000] CPU features: enabling workaround for EL2 vector hardening
[    0.000000] CPU features: enabling workaround for Speculative Store Bypass Disable
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Kernel page table isolation (KPTI)
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129024
[    0.000000] Policy zone: DMA32
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: earlyprintk=serial,ttyAMA0
[    0.000000] console=ttyAMA0,115200n8 earlycon=xenboot
[    0.000000] Memory: 455476K/524288K available (10748K kernel code, 1412K rwdata, 5112K rodata, 1344K init, 380K bss, 36044K reserved, 32768K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=64 to nr_cpu_ids=4.
[    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=4
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] GICv3: Distributor has no Range Selector support
[    0.000000] GICv3: no VLPI support, no direct LPI support
(XEN) d0v0: vGICD: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER4
(XEN) d0v0: vGICD: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER8
(XEN) d0v0: vGICD: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER12
(XEN) d0v0: vGICD: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER16
(XEN) d0v0: vGICD: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER20
(XEN) d0v0: vGICD: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER24
(XEN) d0v0: vGICD: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER28
[    0.000000] GICv3: CPU0: found redistributor 0 region 0:0x00000000080a0000
(XEN) d0v0: vGICR: SGI: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER0
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 62.50MHz (virt).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x1cd42e208c, max_idle_ns: 881590405314 ns
[    0.000108] sched_clock: 56 bits at 62MHz, resolution 16ns, wraps every 4398046511096ns
[    0.017243] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.020478] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 125.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=250000)
[    0.021062] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.031104] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.032772] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.033612] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.034046] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.034320] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.121936] ASID allocator initialised with 32768 entries
[    0.130646] xen:grant_table: Grant tables using version 1 layout
[    0.131832] Grant table initialized
[    0.145062] xen:events: Using FIFO-based ABI
[    0.147228] Xen: initializing cpu0
[    0.174809] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.194598] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.215474] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
(XEN) d0v1: vGICR: SGI: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER0
(XEN) d0v2: vGICR: SGI: unhandled word write 0xffffffff to ICACTIVER0
[    0.273655] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU1
[    0.274338] GICv3: CPU1: found redistributor 1 region 0:0x00000000080c0000
[    0.275368] Xen: initializing cpu1
[    0.275561] CPU1: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000001 [0x411fd070]
[    0.339645] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU2
[    0.339831] GICv3: CPU2: found redistributor 2 region 0:0x00000000080e0000
[    0.340694] Xen: initializing cpu2
[    0.340845] CPU2: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000002 [0x411fd070]
[    0.400734] Detected PIPT I-cache on CPU3
[    0.400925] GICv3: CPU3: found redistributor 3 region 0:0x0000000008100000
[    0.401355] Xen: initializing cpu3
[    0.401498] CPU3: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000003 [0x411fd070]
[    0.574444] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.703442] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated.
[    0.703908] CPU features: detected: GIC system register CPU interface
[    0.704393] CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL0 Support
[    0.704796] CPU features: detected: CRC32 instructions
[    1.039745] CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL1
[    1.046203] alternatives: patching kernel code
[    1.380096] devtmpfs: initialized
[    1.662983] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    1.667044] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    1.709743] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    1.904352] DMI not present or invalid.
[    1.934684] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    2.083444] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    2.327780] audit: type=2000 audit(0.476:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    2.434832] vdso: 2 pages (1 code @ (____ptrval____), 1 data @ (____ptrval____))
[    2.437256] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    2.625009] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic allocations
[    2.628185] xen:swiotlb_xen: Warning: only able to allocate 4 MB for software IO TLB
[    2.643167] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x7bc00000-0x7c000000] (4MB)
[    2.666593] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    2.781142] Internal error: synchronous external abort: 96000010 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[    2.784420] Modules linked in:
[    2.785879] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.20.11 #1
[    2.787890] Hardware name: linux,dummy-virt (DT)
[    2.789880] pstate: 40000005 (nZcv daif -PAN -UAO)
[    2.796098] pc : amba_device_try_add+0x150/0x2a8
[    2.797158] lr : amba_device_try_add+0x13c/0x2a8
[    2.798292] sp : ffff00000807bc30
[    2.799045] x29: ffff00000807bc30 x28: 0000000000000000 
[    2.800351] x27: 0000000000000001 x26: ffff000009272740 
[    2.801523] x25: ffff80003dff3238 x24: ffff00000800d000 
[    2.802827] x23: 0000000000000000 x22: 0000000000001000 
[    2.818140] x21: ffff80003c1256f0 x20: 0000000000000000 
[    2.821090] x19: ffff80003c125400 x18: ffff0000091696c8 
[    2.822412] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000 
[    2.823657] x15: 0000000000000001 x14: ffffffffffffffff 
[    2.824826] x13: 0000000000000000 x12: 0101010101010101 
[    2.826219] x11: 0000000000000020 x10: 0101010101010101 
[    2.828012] x9 : 0000000000000000 x8 : ffff80003c108c80 
[    2.829810] x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : 0000000000000004 
[    2.849524] x5 : 0000000000000001 x4 : ffff80003c920000 
[    2.850898] x3 : 0000000000000000 x2 : ffff00000800dfe0 
[    2.854982] x1 : ffff80003c920000 x0 : 0000000000000000 
[    2.856240] Process swapper/0 (pid: 1, stack limit = 0x(____ptrval____))
[    2.857992] Call trace:
[    2.858729]  amba_device_try_add+0x150/0x2a8
[    2.859697]  amba_device_add+0x18/0xd0
[    2.860546]  of_platform_bus_create+0x2e8/0x370
[    2.861588]  of_platform_populate+0x50/0xc8
[    2.862639]  of_platform_default_populate_init+0xac/0xc8
[    2.864555]  do_one_initcall+0x54/0x158
[    2.865771]  kernel_init_freeable+0x188/0x224
[    2.881225]  kernel_init+0x10/0x100
[    2.882137]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x18
[    2.883266] Code: 35000940 d10082c2 52800000 8b020302 (88dffc41) 
[    2.885516] ---[ end trace fccca99c319bfe50 ]---
[    2.889573] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b
[    2.895687] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[    2.944175] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b ]---
```

It seems that something happens in the procedure of loading **AMBA**. The kernel booted smoothly when I simply run Qemu 6.0.0 and busybox:

`qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -machine virtualization=true -cpu cortex-a57 -machine type=virt -m 4096 -smp 4 -kernel Image.gz -nographic -no-reboot -initrd rootfs.cpio.gz -append "rw root=/dev/ram rdinit=/sbin/init earlyprintk=serial,ttyAMA0 console=ttyAMA0"`

So I think the kernel and rootfs is OK. And with U-boot, it could also boot until loading VFS (AMBA loaded). Then I tried to regenerate the device tree blob file:

```sh
qemu-system-aarch64-600 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -machine virtualization=true -cpu cortex-a57 -machine type=virt -m 4096 -smp 4 -display none -machine dumpdtb=virt-gicv3.dtb
# qemu-system-aarch64: info: dtb dumped to virt-gicv3.dtb. Exiting.
```

But the same problem happens. Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable [ARM PL061](https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/system-ip/system-controllers/peripheral-controllers).
PL061 is an Advanced Microcontroller Bus Architecture (AMBA) compliant controller.

```
# XXX disable pl061 to avoid Linux crash
dtc -I dtb -O dts virt-gicv3.dtb > virt-gicv3.dts
sed 's/compatible = "arm,pl061.*/status = "disabled";/g' virt-gicv3.dts > virt-gicv3-edited.dts
dtc -I dts -O dtb virt-gicv3-edited.dts > virt-gicv3.dtb
```

At least [that's what Xen tests do](https://github.com/xen-project/xen/blob/9bc9fff04ba077c4a9782f12578362d8947c534b/automation/scripts/qemu-alpine-arm64.sh).

Comment: Wow! That's obscure. Thanks for sharing!